# Create Rx.NET Observable in SignalR hub

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, system.reactive, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub that listens to client requests and uses Rx.NET to observe a database table, in order to send back updates to the client that requested them, as soon as they are available. But it looks like the `Observer` instance that is created in the hub, according to the client request, is destroyed (by the GC?) as soon as the method call finishes; therefore, I get no updates.

This is my current `Hub` implementation:

```
public class BookHub : Hub {
    private readonly BookService _service = new BookService();

    public void RequestBookUpdate(string author) {
        BookObserver observer = new BookObserver(Context.connectionId);
        IDisposable unsubscriber = _service.RequestBookUpdate(author, observer);
    }
}
```

The `BookService` returns a LINQ query converted to an `Observable`:

```
public IDisposable RequestBookUpdate(string author, BookObserver observer) {
    var query = from b in db.Book where b.Author.Contains(author) select b;
    IObservable<Book> observable = query.ToObservable();
    IDisposable unsubscriber = observable.Subscribe(observer);
    return unsubscriber;
}
```

The `BookObserver` simply sends back the new retrieved items to the specific client who requested the updates (identified by the `connectionId`):

```
// omissis

private static readonly IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BookHub>();
private readonly string _connectionId;

public BookObserver(string connectionId) {
    connectionId = _connectionId:
}

public void OnNext(Book value) {
    _context.Clients.Client(_connectionId).foundNewBook(value);
}
```

I don't care about the `BookService` instance being destroyed, but I want the `BookObserver` to stay alive, so I can call `unsubscriber.Dispose()` only when the client disconnects. Is this possible?

Comment: It would be insightful to have a bit more context. For what purpose do you want to keep the Observer undisposed until the connection ends?

Comment: I'd like to _listen_ to the same SQL query and get updates as soon as some new data is committed. Since data is committed into the database from a separate process (which I don't have control on) the only solutions to do this would be either polling (both the database and a Web service) or observing an `IQueryable` with Rx.NET and sending updates through a WebSocket.

Comment: Creating a query aqainst an IQueryable doesn't guarantee that you will receive all future elements. For this, you need a Query Provider capable of providing the future elements. `db` doesn't seem to be capable of that functionality.

Comment: As an aside, is it possible to remove these elements from the database, and is that a case you intend to handle?

Comment: Element removal is currently not one of our requisites.

Comment: Of what type is `db`? (What type of Database are you using)

Comment: `db` is a `DbContext` currently on version 4 of the Entity Framework. The databse instance is Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the `db` instance? If the db instance is disposed of, it's query consumers will also be cleaned up (or fail).

Comment: The `db` lifetime is tied only to the `BookService` that creates it with `MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();`. Of course, `MyDatabasEntities` is auto-generated by the Entity Framework and extends `DbContext`.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `.ToObservable()` will turn a single database query into something that repeatedly queries the database for changes. It doesn't. You need to create a query based on `Observable.Interval` and make the repeated database calls yourself to get the new records and then return them. Your observables signature should end up being something like `IObservable<IEnumerable<Book>>` as each call to the database will return zero or more books.

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69326634-c23b-4bee-8a32-f3148c2b4b62/how-to-make-ef-select-asynchronous?forum=rx). What I want is still achievable with a combination of [`OnChangeObservable`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6c4f681-b342-4f3c-92f9-5a013bf93d4c/anyway-to-use-entity-framwork-to-observe-changes-to-a-table?forum=rx) and `SqlCommand`. Has anyone ever used it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Observer` is being automatically disposed when it receives a call to `OnComplete`. This is actually a *very good* pattern, as it means you don't have to manually dispose of `Subscription`s like this:

```
Observable.Range(0, 100)
    .Subscribe(...);
```

or

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Take(10)
    .Subscribe();
```

So, to make sure your observer doesn't get disposed until it *wants* to be disposed, you can concat another empty, never completing, observable to your source.

```
IObservable<Book> observable = query.ToObservable()
    .Concat(Observable.Never<Book>());
```

However, depending on what you're attempting to do, it may be better to handle this elsewhere, such as the client.

Comment: The whole point is to make something like a continuous query (observable, in this case) that notifies the observer as soon as some data changes. This way, the observer can notify and update the client via SignalR.

The power of RX (and WebSockets) is lost if the observer is automatically disposed when only "regular-queried" data have been returned; wouldn't you agree?

Comment: If the Observable is completing, it means your query has no more elements available. The problem is not with the Observable or the Observer, it's with the producer. In this case, the producer is the Database, and the database is only feeding you the existing elements, not the future elements.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because executing the same method from a regular Rest service and adding a row in the database produces a OnNext call.

Comment: Can you a comparative Rest code example in the question?

Comment: It's the same exact call to the same BookService, but it is made from an ApiController. Of course, that was done for testing only, since new results couldn't be pushed to clients :-)

Comment: I have updated the original question with some code from the `ApiController`.

Comment: For the record, the reason the observable is completing is because EntityFramework doesn't support continuous queries. What's happening in your code is that an `IQueryable` is being converted to an `IObservable`, but the underlying data retrieval doesn't change. It only returns *existing* records. So Rx is doing exactly what it's designed to do, and what it should do. Entity Framework just doesn't provide the functionality you had expected it to provide.